# Add custom column to woocommerce report - csv

Tags: wordpress, csv, woocommerce, export

I've got a question - is it possible to add one more column (which will present data from custom field) to csv export file in woocommerce? all necessary data is stored for each order as meta_key: 'authors_income'. I have no idea how to make it. I've tried to adapt below code, but it doesnt work:

```
function wpg_add_columns($cols) {
    $cols['wc_settings_tab_payment_method'] = __('Payment Method', 'mytheme');
    return $cols;
}
add_filter('wpg_order_columns', 'wpg_add_columns');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Let me know this goes.

```
<?php

//Step 1: Add field to column
function wpg_add_columns($cols) {

    $cols['wc_settings_tab_authors_income'] = __('Authors Income', 'mytheme');
    return $cols;
}
add_filter('wpg_order_columns', 'wpg_add_columns');


//Step 2: Add same column to settings, so that it will appear in settings page.
function wpg_add_fields($settings) {

    $settings['authors_income'] = array(
                                'name' => __( 'Authors Income', 'woocommerce-simply-order-export' ),
                                'type' => 'checkbox',
                                'desc' => __( 'Authors Income', 'woocommerce-simply-order-export' ),
                                'id'   => 'wc_settings_tab_authors_income'
                            );

    return $settings;

}
add_filter('wc_settings_tab_order_export', 'wpg_add_fields');


//Note: Notice that in above step, id attribute is identical to that of array key in step 1. ( wc_settings_tab_authors_income )
//Step 3: Add it to csv.
function csv_write( &$csv, $od, $fields ) {

    if( !empty( $fields['wc_settings_tab_authors_income'] ) && $fields['wc_settings_tab_authors_income'] === true ){
        $authors_income = get_post_meta( $od->id, 'authors_income', true );
        array_push( $csv, $authors_income );
    }

}
add_action('wpg_add_values_to_csv', 'csv_write', 10, 3);
```